# Selectize.js conflict with bootstrap select element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selectize.js

I'm trying to implement the `selectize.js` library in my application but it seems like it conflicts with bootstrap. Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#country').selectize();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/css/selectize.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->




<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Country</label>
    <select id="country" class="form-control">
      <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
      <option value="US">US</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
```

**Answer:**

Just removed the class `form-control` in select element.

Answer (score 0):

try this one  add value

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Country</label>
    <select id="country" class="form-control">
      <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
      <option value="US">US</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add a snippet.

Comment: sorry i can not do this